# Why do I need ping-pong to detect websocket connection drops if I am already reconnecting onclose()?

Tags: javascript, websocket, ping, pong

I have code that connects to an external WebSocket API, which looks like follows:

```
const WebSocket = require('ws')

const ws = new WebSocket('wss://example.com/')

const connectExternalAPI() => {
    ws.onopen = () => { ws.send(JSON.stringify('example': 'message')) }

    ws.onerror = (event) => { console.error(event) }

    ws.onmessage = (event) => { console.log(event.data) }

    ws.onclose = (event) => {
        console.error(event)
        setTimeout(connectExternalAPI, 10000)
    }
}
```

Since I already try to reconnect to the API every time the connection gets an `onclose`, what is the necessity to additionally implement `ping-pong` to detect connection drops (and try to reconnect) when this already accomplishes the same thing?

Are there circumstances under which `onclose` is not triggered even though the connection may have dropped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the connection is explicitly closed, you will get an `onclose` almost immediately, but if the connection is broken, for instance when you disconnect the ethernet cable, it will take some time to get an `onclose`, probably not before TCP detects loss of connectivity. This can take many minutes, depending on your settings.

It doesn't have to be Ping/Pong by the way; a heartbeat sent by the server and received and processed in the browser will also work and is sometimes easier to implement.

Comment: I see, does it eventually always get an `onclose` event though once TCP has detected the loss in connectivity? I don't mind they delay if its a couple minutes only.

Comment: As far as I know and have experienced, he said carefully 8-), it will eventually come, yes. In Firefox, I have seen up to 10 minutes, though. I always put in a server heartbeat, to make sure.

Comment: Thanks! In my case, my server itself is connecting to an external web-socket so it won't be browser detected but my node app will be detecting it.

Comment: If you have full control I suppose you could somehow set TCP User Timeout, as I think it is called officially, to 10s or some such and be done with it.

Comment: Oh okay great, will look into it. Thank you!